# Gtk show and hide containers on button click

Tags: c, widget, gtk3, glade

I'm working on a simple app. I basically have a GUI made in Glade. I'm using C.

I have on the top a bar about 10 buttons. I want to press, for example, button 1 and I want my low-half screen (which is a box with a fixed and some buttons) to show.

However if a press the button 2 on the top bar I want my lower-half screen to hide that content an replace it with some new one. I know I can do it manually with widget_hide and show one by one, but is there any way I can do it with glade containers?

```
GtkWidget *btn = ptr[2];
GtkWidget *fx = ptr[1];
GtkWidget *holder = ptr[3];
    if(gtk_toggle_button_get_active(btn)){
        gtk_fixed_put(holder,fx,0,0);
        gtk_widget_show(fx);
    }else{
        gtk_widget_hide(fx);
    }
```

That's a really basic idea, `btn` being the button I press, `holder` being the fixed container inside the box, and `fx` being the fixed container of the widgets I want to show/hide and replace with other fixed with different widgets.

Kinda hard to explain myself. Basically y press a button for example each button its a different window, like changing a div and it's contents on HTML.

Comment: If you're having a hard time explaining the problem, that's usually a good sign that you need to dig into it a little deeper.

Comment: Imagine the window, split in two halfs, top and bottom, top half has 4 buttons, the contents of the lower half depends on the button is pressed.

Comment: Maybe an image can make it more clear? If I understand you correctly, it's not possible to switch widgets with glade only. You still have to write some code. Also take a look at `GtkStack`, `GtkExpander` and `GtkRevealer`.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what design you exactly want. Just thinking from my side: I am having a python example app where I load several windows at init.

```
    ...
    self.controlwindow = builder.get_object("scoreboard_control_window")
    self.viewwindow = builder.get_object("scoreboard_view_window")
    self.logdialog = builder.get_object("scoreboard_log_dialog")
    self.logoffdialog = builder.get_object("scoreboard_logoff_confirm")
    self.logcanceldialog = builder.get_object("scoreboard_logcancel_confirm")
    self.resetdialog = builder.get_object("scoreboard_resetconfirm")
    self.exitdialog = builder.get_object("scoreboard_exitconfirm")
```

And by using  show/hide like  GUI.controlwindow.show()  or          self.logoffdialog.show() or self.logoffdialog.hide(), I control the pop-up / hiding of dialog and entries windows.